# No leading zeros for months R

Tags: r, date, format

`format()` in R does not have an obvious option to display the month without leading 0 (and the same with the year). Is there another way to get this result? The solution should allow the user to flexibly choose whether 0s are to be omitted only for the day or the month or the year or for any combination.

in: `as.Date("2005-09-02")`

out: `2/9/5`

or 0 only removed for month:

out: `2/9/05`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution with `sub`:

```
x <- as.Date("2005-09-02")
sub("..0?(.+)-0?(.+)-0?(.+)", "\\3/\\2/\\1", x)
# [1] "2/9/5"
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, this seems promising. How would I access a group >9? \\10 does not work...

Answer (score 8):

You can try this.

```
x <- as.Date(c("2005-09-02", "2005-10-20", "2010-10-20"))

gsub("0(\\d)", "\\1", format(x, "%d/%m/%y"))
# [1] "2/9/5"    "20/10/5"  "20/10/10"
```

But keep in mind that doing this on a vector of dates from different centuries will make things a bit confusing when you go back to look at them later.

Comment: What about 2005-10-20 ?

Comment: @G.Grothendieck - thanks I think my edit should take care of that

Comment: Ok, works if all leading 0s are to be stripped. But what, if the year should keep its zero and month not:

as in out: # [1] "2/9/05"    "20/10/05"  "20/10/10"
??

Comment: @AndriSignorell - that's not what your question asks for. It asks how to strip leading zeros from everything including the year

Comment: @Richard: The example was unclear, sorry. I need a solution to flexibly remove leading 0s either on m or on y or on both.

Answer (score -4):

You can do this but you need to set it as a character because that format is not an actual date format.

```
X = "2005-09-02"
date = paste(substr(X,10,10),"/",substr(X,7,7),"/",substr(X,4,4),sep='')
```

Comment: This is incorrect.  The goal isn't to print one digit per field, but to suppress leading `0`'s.