# date format without leading zeros - R

Tags: r, date, data-manipulation

I have dates in a character vector and I'm looking for a way to transform it to date format with `as.Date()`:

```
vector <- c("15/1/2019", "5/5/2019")
```

However, `as.Date(vector, format="%d/%m/%Y")` receives as input characters with zeros leading. And I have found plenty of solutions for:

```
Input: "15/01/2019"
Output: "15/1/2019"
```

However, I need exactly the opposite to make `as.Date()` to work:

```
Input: "15/1/2019" "5/5/2019"
Output: "15/01/2019" "05/05/2019"
```

Is there any specific formatting for `format` argument? Or I have to use a `substr()` solution?

Comment: I've edited so as the dates in `vector` are quoted and match the output example.

Comment: (also `vector` is an R function so not the greatest variable name)

Comment: I'm so confused. What are the "plenty of solutions" to generate 15/1/2019 on output from an input of 15/01/2019?

Comment: It took me 5 seconds get these two: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25387160/formatting-a-date-in-r-without-leading-zeros and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27584346/no-leading-zeros-for-months-r

Comment: Why the downvote by the way? I can't find any solution for this out of this thread

Comment: I've edited my answer because it is clear from your comments that you are confusing the appearance of a Date object with the appearance of a formatted date string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `strftime`.

```
strftime(as.Date(inp, format="%d/%m/%Y"), format="%d/%m/%Y")
# [1] "15/01/2019" "05/05/2019"
```

***Data***

```
inp <- c("15/1/2019", "5/5/2019")
```

Comment: There's nothing magical: the`as.Date` reads character and converts into date, the `strftime` creates an output in desired format. The trick is to both specify correctly. See `?strftime`.

Comment: Thanks!. By the way, I had to add `%>% as.Date()` as the class of your result is character.

Comment: By your last comment I think you are confusing the appearance of a Date object with the appearance of a formatted date string.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand the issue. `as.Date()` works as expected on your input:

```
vector <- c("15/1/2019", "5/5/2019")
dates <- as.Date(vector, format = "%d/%m/%Y")

dates
[1] "2019-01-15" "2019-05-05"
```

To get the desired output, you use `format`:

```
format(dates, "%d/%m/%Y")
[1] "15/01/2019" "05/05/2019"
```

**EDIT**

From your comments, it's clear that you are confusing two different things.

To get a Date object using `as.Date()`, you need to tell it the format of the input date character string. You have "day-month-year". So you supply that to `as.Date()`:

```
as.Date(vector, format = "%d/%m/%Y")
```

The result will always be displayed in the console as year-month-day (YYYY-MM-DD).

*Displaying the date* in a chosen format is something different. Now we are formatting the Date object back to a character string:

```
format(dates, "%d/%m/%Y")
```

To summarise: a properly-converted Date object will always display in the console as YYYY-MM-DD. Formatting that object as a string is a different operation.

I hope this clears things up.

Comment: It doesn't for me. It gives me `[1] "0015-01-20" "0005-05-20"`

Comment: You're getting that result because you omitted the `format` argument to `as.Date()`.